# Are there good tutorials for VST plugin creation in JUCE C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, audio, vst, juce

I want to make VST plugins in C++. I read that the JUCE library is better than using the Steinberg SDK. My problem is that when I Google tutorials it only covers generic topics pertaining to application development only, not specialized audio plugin interfaces that the library was initially designed for.

I am looking for a tutorial that covers making a VST plugin (maybe a simple effect, like a lowpass filter) with the JUCE framework. Or, if anybody could tell me about better or easier ways to develop VST Plugins in Visual Studio (2008) and link to resources that will help me get started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way to develop VST plugins, they require knowledge of advanced signal processing and programming.

Here are some links that can help you out with your plugin development

[KVR Audio: DSP / Plugin / Host Development](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30071&sid=702bf56e5331dc6b97c4a7bddce04065)
[KVR Audio: How To Create VST Plugins](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=329696)

For JUCE C++ Framework there aren't many full featured tutorials as such so you will have to learn by reading code and understanding it.

For Filter Design I would suggest checking out **DSPFilters** by  vinniefalco. This is a collection of C++ classes for signal processing. It uses JUCE C++ Framework. So I suggest you check that out.

https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters

You can also check out TAL Plugins. Some of these plugins were made with JUCE C++ and their source code is available for free on their website.

For the Filter there is Tal-Filter, download is underneath source code section.

http://kunz.corrupt.ch/Products/TAL-Filter

For a Subtractive Synth Tal-NoiseMaker, download for source code is underneath source code section.

http://kunz.corrupt.ch/Products/TAL-NoiseMaker

Both of these plugins source code are open source and are using JUCE C++ Framework.

Comment: I have a decent understanding of DSP, I've spent alot of time using VSTs and making presets with them. Also, I've used SynthMaker for creating VSTs, the visual editing made making the GUI easy but I still used code modules. So I have the basic concepts of FIR/IIR filters and coefficients, but just now realizing (thanks to you) not enough to stray from visual vst development. Kudos on the DSPFilters using JUCE!! And I use TAL plugins from time to time I didn't realize they were open-source!! Great stuff here thanks! :) I'll take a peek at those but read up on DSP more before trying to develop

Comment: Keep at it and don't give up. it can get frustrating at times. I am glad that i can be of some help to you.

Comment: Hey it seems that the TAL Plugins aren't open source anymore, do anyone of you know about other open source juce synthesizers?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays I recommend using [WDL](http://www.cockos.com/wdl/) instead of JUCE. WDL is free for commercial use, and you can build Win/Mac, 32/64 Bit, VST2/VST3/AU/RTAS/AAX and standalone from one codebase.

There's a [tutorial series](http://martin-finke.de/blog/tags/making_audio_plugins.html) showing how to get started.